# Return values of custom authentication in Django REST Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

I'm trying to write my basic custom authentication for Django REST Framework. I have the following auth backend:

```
class JoeAuth(authentication.BaseAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
        username = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_USER')
        if not username:
            return

        try:
            user = User.objects.get(krb_name=username, active=True).name
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            raise PermissionDenied('Unauthorized user')

        return (user, None)
```

Accompanied with a view:

```
@api_view()
def hello(request):
    return Response(data='hello')
```

And of course enabled in `settings.py`:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'helloworld.auth.JoeAuth',
    )
}
```

Now, if a request comes in and does not specify the `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_USER` header, the `authenticate()` function returns `None`. According so DRF docs:

> To implement a custom authentication scheme, subclass BaseAuthentication and override the .authenticate(self, request) method. The method should return a two-tuple of (user, auth) if authentication succeeds, or None otherwise.
>
> In some circumstances instead of returning None, you may want to raise an AuthenticationFailed exception from the .authenticate() method.

A `None` means authentication failed and should ideally return 401 or 403. However, in practice this doesn't seem to be the case. A request without the `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_USER` is simply allowed and 200 is returned:

```
$ http http://127.0.0.1:8000/ HTTP_X_FORWARDED_USER:joe
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

"hello"

$ http http://127.0.0.1:8000/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

"hello"
```

Am I misunderstanding the documentation in the sense that a `None` is considered a successful authentication attempt?

Comment: Are you sure your username is None? What if change `if not username` to `if True`?

Comment: @seuling Yes, I'm sure. Note the example HTTPie calls where one specifies the header and the other doesn't, both resulting in the same 200 status code.

Comment: What if change to `return None` from `return`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are confusing authentication and authorization(permissions in Django). What the authentication does is identifyy the user, however it does not in any way, restrict the user - that is the work of authorization(permission). The permission classes do the work of checking the rights a user has over a particular resource. 
From what I can see, it seems you have a default global `AllowAny` permission set, which allows anyone access. You need to set the permission to restrict the endpoint to only authenticated users.

In your case, you need to add a `permission_classes` to the view or use global perm issions in DRF settings. 
You can add permission classes to a function-based API view this way:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.decorators import permission_classes, api_view


@api_view()
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def hello(request):
    return Response(data='hello')
```